# dmake target specific variables

Tags: dmake

This topic has been discussed a few times, but the answers only seem to cover GNU make. For this particular Makefile, I'd like it to be a single cross-platform file assuming GNU make for Mac and Linux, and dmake for Windows.

I'm trying to figure out how to assign macros/variables for only a specified target using dmake.
In this case, I'm going to use it for preprocessor definitions.

I'd like to add

```
CPPFLAGS += -DINITIAL
```

to an 'initial' target and

```
CPPFLAGS += -DUPDATE
```

to an 'update' target.

Using GNU make, we can achieve this by the following:

```
initial: CPPFLAGS += -DINITIAL
initial:
        ...

update: CPPFLAGS += -DUPDATE
update:
        ...
```

but unfortunately, it breaks the build using dmake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dmake, the syntax needs to be slightly changed to

```
initial ?= CPPFLAGS += -DINITIAL
```

Resource: http://www.openoffice.org/tools/dmake/dmake_4.3.html#lbAS

Wrapping the different syntaxes in OS checks allows for a cohesive Makefile .